# minimal docker for golang gin REST API endpoint

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, go-gin

I can build a simple REST API endpoint with `gin` + `golang` using [this tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin):

```bash
$ go mod init translator/golang # <--- arbitrary name, right ?
go: creating new go.mod: module translator/golang
go: to add module requirements and sums:
    go mod tidy # <--- yes boss !
$ go mod tidy                  
go: finding module for package github.com/gin-gonic/gin
go: found github.com/gin-gonic/gin in github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
$ go run .
# ... omitted log messages ...
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on localhost:5000
```

When I send an http `GET` request everything goes fine:

```bash
#                          |---------------| this is my route
curl http://localhost:5000/translator/golang
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Blue Train", # <--- expected output of the tutorial, good !
        "artist": "John Coltrane",
        "price": 56.99
    },
# ... omitted ...
]
```

When I try to "dockerize" this process, it doesn't work:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.21.5
COPY main.go main.go
RUN go mod init translator/golang
# RUN go mod tidy uncommenting this gives an error
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["go", "run"]
```

- If I use `go mod tidy` (like I did locally) I get an error

```bash
$ docker build --tag host --file Dockerfile .
# ... omitted for brevity ...
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY main.go main.go                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN go mod init translator/golang                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN go mod tidy                                                                                                                0.1s
------                                                                                                                                              
 > [4/4] RUN go mod tidy:
0.129 $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
# ... omitted for brevity ...
```

- If I *don't* use `go mod tidy`

  - I get *no* errors during the `docker build`
  - But, I fail to connect to the dockerized server

```bash
$ docker run -p 8000:5000 -d -t --name scfrontgo host
$ curl http://localhost:8000/translator/golang # <--- (from another window)
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000 after 5 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: `...serving HTTP on localhost:...` often is an indication that the service is configured to listen only on the container-private localhost interface at 127.0.0.1, and it will be unreachable from outside its own container.  You'd need to change this to 0.0.0.0.  Does [Can't connect to Go Server in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769426/cant-connect-to-go-server-in-docker-container) (and more specifically [this answer](/a/71980210) help you?

Comment: @DavidMaze it still doesn't work. When I do `docker exec` and get inside the docker, I see that the docker comes with a `GOPATH` which seem to cause problems

Answer (score 0):

I think my problems originated from trying to run `go mod init` *inside* the docker. When I looked in [this docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/#create-a-dockerfile-for-the-application), I saw that the `go mod init` should be run *on the local machine*, then needs to be copied with `COPY`. Here is the complete `Dockerfile` that worked for me:

```
FROM golang:1.20.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY main.go ./
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /translator
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["/translator"]
```

And `main.go` is similar to the tutorial except for the route mentioned in the comment by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze):

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/translator/golang", getAlbums)
    router.Run("0.0.0.0:5000")
}
```